# 24412: Not valid because the interior of a polygon with rings (2) and (1) is not connected

Tags: polygon, geometry, sql-server, error, invalid-data

I've got geography in sqlserver that is invalid.  Running IsValidDetailed() I get the reason as

`24412: Not valid because the interior of a polygon with rings (2) and (1) is not connected`.

But I don't know what that means.  my polygon does have 3 holes in it, is it to do with ring orientation?

Comment: Maybe your holes touch each others and the border of the main polygon so that the polygon gets split in halves. If you could add your geometry as WKT there would be no need for guessing.

Comment: the WKT is massive, I was hoping someone could say what I should look for from the error message, the holes aren't anywhere near each other or the edge.

Answer (score 2):

It may have something to do with the ring orientation and or how the interior of the polygons and their connection. This web page [New Spatial Features in SQL Server Code-Named](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4136.new-spatial-features-in-sql-server-code-named-denali.aspx)provides

> several significant enhancements to spatial types, such as support for new subtypes of circular arcs, new and updated methods and aggregates for all subtypes, improved precision, and updates to the geography type.

[image]

> Circular arcs are supported by geometry and geography and can be defined using Well-known Text (WKT), Well-known Binary (WKB), and Geography Markup Language (GML) in SQL Server Code-Named “Denali.”

if you are receiving error `24412' based on [IsValidDetailed (geography Data Type)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/isvaliddetailed-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)

[image]

> The following illustration shows the difference between circular arcs and linear strings for the same set of coordinates.

In general any 244xx refers to

Returns a message that can help to i>dentify problems with a spatial object that is not valid. When the object is not valid, only the first error is returned. When the object is valid, a value of 24400 is returned.

Specifically

`24412`

> Not valid because the interior of a polygon with rings {0} and {1} is not connected.